# Change color when mouse over from pdf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, pdf, alivepdf, purepdf

I have a task:
In my document I created some link. If I click it I go to some place from my document. And from time of click appears a highlight. I want to highlight appears from time mouse over. Whether exist some way to do it?
I work with Flash, AS3 and AlivePdf library to create pdf (can work with PurePdf). Does anybody know how do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links in PDF don't have rollover appearances. Instead, create a button field and set the MouseUp action to be the equivalent of what you want the link to do, set the background and outline to be transparent, it will appear to be the same as a link. Then set the MouseEnter and MouseExit events to change the fillColor property to highlight when the mouse enters the rectangle defined by the button, and back to transparent when the mouse exits; two separate scripts. You'll need to be familiar with Acrobat JavaScript in order to add these things.

Also, most browser-based PDF viewers won't respect the script so your users may not get a consistent experience.